# Expectation of a function of three random variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, independence

I have three random variables $X, Y,$ and $Z$. $X=a$ whenever $Y \geq b$, and $X=0$ whenever $Y<b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. I have some function $g(X,Y,Z)$ of all three variables. I know the pdfs of $f_y$ and $f_z$. Also, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. However, $X$ and $Y$ are dependent since $X$ is a function of $Y$.
My question is how do I find $E(g(X,Y,Z))$ over the random variables I have?

Comment: You do a double integral over all $(y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, treating the region $y\geq b$ and $y<b$ separately.

Comment: Since $X=h(Y,Z)$ you are evaluating $E[g(h(Y,Z),Y,Z)]=\int_{(y,z)}g(h(y,z),y,z)f_{Y,Z}(y,z)dydz$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you so much for your feedback professor! However, X is a function of Y only, which means X=h(Y). Also, since Y and Z are independent, does that mean the joint pdf fy,z is fy*fz? 
Thanks again for your feedback!

Comment: Here I have given you a general result that holds when $X$ can be a function of both $Y$ and $Z$, which includes the special case when $X$ is only a function of $Y$.  Also the result I gave is for any joint PDF, including the case when the PDF has a product form. In general if we have a vector of random variables $(W_1, ..., W_n)$ and a joint PDF, then $$E[\psi(W_1, ..., W_n)] = \int_{(w_1, ..., w_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n} \psi(w_1, ..., w_n)f_{W_1,...,W_n}(w_1,...,w_n)dw_1...dw_n$$ assuming $\psi$ is measurable and $\psi(W_1, ..., W_n)$ is a random variable with finite expectation.

Comment: @Michael Thank you professor for your assistance! That explains a lot!